# Vb.net hyperlink Dataview and listing between price range

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, gridview, hyperlink

I am working on a assignment in which I have to use VB.net and Access database in order to make a bookstore. One of the requirements is that I have to make a table with book titles and customer names with a hyperlink on the title and customer name which will redirect them to a new page. I have the table working, but I am not able to add a hyperlink to one of the columns in the table. Also there is a searching feature where I have to print all the books between a price range (ex. $20 < price <= $30) I have the radio buttons setup but I am not able to do the actual searching and get good values. My code is below:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class CustomerSearching
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        RadioButton1.Visible = False
        RadioButton2.Visible = False
        RadioButton3.Visible = False
        RadioButton4.Visible = False
        RadioButton5.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("~/bookstore.accdb"))
        conn.Open()

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Response.Redirect("Customer.aspx")
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OleDb.12.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("~/bookstore.accdb"))
        RadioButton1.Visible = True
        RadioButton2.Visible = True
        RadioButton3.Visible = True
        RadioButton4.Visible = True
        RadioButton5.Visible = True

        If (RadioButton1.Checked) Then
            conn.Open()
            Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE price < $10.00"
            Dim dbcomm As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
            Dim dbread = dbcomm.ExecuteReader()
            bookSearching.DataSource = dbread
            bookSearching.DataBind()
            dbread.Close()
            conn.Close()
        End If

    End Sub

    Protected Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

For the hyperlink I used the vb option to design and dragged a sqlDataSource and a gridview and linked the two together with my bookstore.accdb file. You're help is much appreciated. Thanks a lot.